# Android 4.1+ PopupWindow Simplest Example

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-view, android-menu

I want simple and clear example for PopupWindow (such simple as [popupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)).
I want to replace popupMenu with popupWindow.
Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null, false),
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    true
);
popup.showAtLocation(
    findViewById(R.id.main),
    Gravity.END | Gravity.TOP,
    dpToPx(16),
    dpToPx(42)
);
```